# Execute SQL Server stored procedure in VBA with multiple outputs

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that I am trying to execute from Excel via some VBA code. However, the stored procedure has two outputs (see below).

My record set is only pulling in the first table (added 0 error messages...) whereas I want to pull in the second table.

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxyLi.png

Here is my code, compiled from other sources I found on here:

```
Sub RefreshBarcodes()
Dim Database As String
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim strconn As String
Dim SQLServer As String
Dim Session As String
Dim strSQLCommandOne As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Master").Activate
Database = Worksheets("Master").Cells(5, "H").Value
SQLServer = Worksheets("Master").Cells(4, "H").Value
Session = Worksheets("Master").Cells(6, "H").Value

'Connect to Database
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
strconn = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=" & SQLServer & ";Initial Catalog = " & _
Database & "; INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI; "
con.Open strconn

'Set SQL Commands
strSQLCommandOne = "set nocount on; exec spGetSessionSourceCounts 'HNW-CLU-001-024_01_0005'"

'Open Recordset
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Execute and copy to Excel
rs.Open strSQLCommandOne, strconn
    rs.MoveFirst
    Worksheets("Session").Activate
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close

Worksheets("Master").Activate
Cells(6, "H").Value = "Session updated"

con.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Excel output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7i3B.png

I would love to be able to pull in the first (error message) and second results (session info), but mainly need only the second table. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: you need to write a better stored proc to capture error with output params.

Comment: Maybe you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677539(v=vs.85).aspx  (never done this myself though)

Comment: Another link that might be helpful to you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245179

Comment: What does the SP look like?

Comment: I was able to use rs.NextRecordset to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the second recordset, you need to execute this line:-

```
'Activate the next available recordset
Set rs = rs.NextRecordset

If Not rs Is Nothing Then

  'Add code in here

End If
```

Comment: Awesome, got it to work. Just created rs2 and stored the next recordset there. Thanks!